# Displaying random digits before final number with setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, counter, setinterval

I have 3 divs (#digit1, #digit2, #digit3), representing 3 digits of a known number (eg: 459). I would like to display 20 random numbers from 0 to 9 (every 100 milliseconds) for **each** digit before displaying the actual number.

Using jQuery, I am able to display the first digit as follows:

```
    function displayInterval(callback,currentnumber) {
        x = 0;
        var interval = window.setInterval(function () {

           callback();

           if (++x === 20) {
               window.clearInterval(interval);
                $("#digit1").html(currentnumber);                  
           }
        }, 100);
    }

    var number1="4";    
    var number2="5";
    var number3="9";    


    displayInterval(function () {
        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        $("#digit1").html(randomnumber);
    },number1);
```

If I add 2 more calls to displayInterval, it only works for 1 digit, and the other two keep displaying random numbers forever.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Note: The above is just a simplified example of what I need. My number can have 1 to 6 digits and will have to put a space if there are more than 3 digits (eg: 12 450), which is why I need to put each digit in a separate div.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array to store numbers. and put gap between each three numbers. 
[**jsFiddle Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/qm6eB/4/)

*You should put a div for each of your numbers as you said in the question (check out the demo).*


Change your JavaScript to this and also see the **demo's HTML code**.

```
function displayInterval(callback) {
     x = 0;
     var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
           callback();
           if (++x === 20) {
               window.clearInterval(interval);

               var nums = $("div[num]");
               var max  = $("div[num]").reverse().attr('num');
               var i = max, j=1;
               $.each( nums, function( key, value ) {
                   if(j%3==0) {
                       $("div[num='"+i+"']").html("&nbsp"+$(this).attr("value"));
                   } else {
                       $("div[num='"+i+"']").html($(this).attr("value"));
                   }
                   i--;j++;
               });                 
           }
    }, 100);
}

displayInterval(function () {
    var nums = $("div[num]");
    var max  = $("div[num]").reverse().attr('num');
    var i = max, j=1;
    $.each( nums, function( key, value ) {
         var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+"";
         if(j%3==0 && i != max) {
             $("div[num='"+i+"']").html("&nbsp"+randomnumber);
         } else {
             $("div[num='"+i+"']").html(randomnumber);
         }
         i--;j++;
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I really need all the digits in separate divs. As stated in my question, if the number has more than 3 digits, there has to be a space (eg: 12 450).